# merge results in more rows than one of the data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames, the first contains 9994 rows and the second contains 60431 rows. I want to merge the two data frames such that the merged data frame contains combined columns of both data frames but only contains 9994 rows.

However, I get more than 9994 rows upon merge. How can I make sure this does not happen?

```
df1 = readRDS('data1.RDS')
nrow(df1)
# [1] 9994

df2 = readRDS('data2.RDS')
nrow(df2)
# [1] 60431

df = merge(df1,df2,by=c("col1","col2"))
nrow(df)
# [1] 10057

df = merge(df1,df2,by=c("col1","col2"),all.x=TRUE)
nrow(df)
# [1] 10057
nrow(na.omit(df))
# [1] 10057
```

EDIT : Following akrun's comment.
Yes, there were duplicates in the second data frame

```
nrow(unique(df2[,c("col1","col2")]))
# [1] 60263
nrow(df2)
# [1] 60431
```

How can I take only one row from a data frame if there are multiple for the same {col1,col2} combination. When I merge, I would like to have only 9994 rows.

Comment: Can you check whether there are duplicates for 'col1', and 'col2' in each of the datasets?  If that is the case, you may create a sequence index, grouped by 'col1' and 'col2' in each of the dataset and merge by 'col1', 'col2', and the 'indx'.  Another option would be using `match`.  But, without a small example, it is difficult to test

Comment: @akrun, thanks akrun. I have made an edit above. please see. How can I take only row for the col1,col2 combination so as to end up with as many rows as in the first data frame upon merge?

Comment: You may need to create a sequence index as I commented earlier.  Without an example data, it is not easy to test.  Please show some reproducible example

Comment: You will need to create a sequence to index this as akrun has mentioned.

Comment: I think the `indx` will not solve the problem. I think it is necessary to decide on what to do with repeated cases in `df2`, i.e, take the first, last, average, etc. in order to have just the `df1` with extra columns from `df2`.

Answer (score 2):

This should work, be sure to sort `df2` first so you select the right rows.

```
df = merge(
  df1,
  df2[!duplicated(df2[, c("col1","col2")]), ],
  by=c("col1","col2"),
  all.x=TRUE
)
```

What happens here: I merge the two data frames by the columns we want to merge by, but I first select only the first occurrence of any combination of `col1` and `col2` from the second `data.frame` `df2`.

`duplicated` checks if lines are duplicated if called with a `data.frame`. I select `col1` and `col2` from `df2`, so `duplicated` returns `TRUE` for rows with the same `col1` and `col2` but differences in other cols. Then I select only the rows which are not duplicated.

(Read the `[`-expressions carefully, and check the function calls from the inside out, to get the intermediate results)

edit: added explanation as suggested in comments

Comment: Can you also please add an explanation of the code?

Comment: When I copy the solution code to R Studio, I get four unexpected / unmatched opening and closing bracket complaints, even though the code appears correct in this respect.  Anybody know why?

Comment: The parenthesis in "!duplicated(" appears to be unmatched.  What worked for me: df = merge(
  df1,
  df2[!duplicated(df2[, c("col1","col2")]), ],
  by=c("col1","col2"),
  all.x=TRUE
)

Comment: Thank you, I corrected the answer accordingly